# Is it possible to calculate the logical expression A ^ B v C?

Tags: logic

In my theory notes, logical AND $\land$ and logical OR $\lor$ are equivalent in precedence. So then is the expression $A \land B \lor C$ valid, i.e. can I compute it, without parenthesis?

Comment: The two ways of parsing it are certainly not equivalent. You should note that a more common convention is that it's $(A\land B)\lor C$.

Comment: In our situation its explicitly not the convention.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not. Consider $A$ false and $B,C$ true. Then $f\wedge (t\vee t) = f$ and $(f\wedge t)\vee t = t$.

Answer (score 0):

No, without parentheses or a convention about which connective is the stronger connective, the expression is ambiguous, since $(A \wedge B) \vee C$ and $A \wedge (B \vee C)$ are not equivalent.

Comment: As I was thinking. In fact our convention is that they are of same connectivity.

Comment: Right, there convention is that they are equally strong: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Binding_Priority.